# how to get the current build variant from android gradle file

Tags: android, gradle

I have a scenario where based on the build variant i have to run a task.
application is using the productFlavour,so its generating debug and release version for the two product flavors.

All i want is to store the current selected build type of the product flavour in a variable in gradle itself.

i have tried the folowing code

```
task getflavour(){
android.applicationVariants.all {         com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant variant ->
   println "values of variant ${variant.productFlavors[0].name}"
    println "assemble ${variant.flavorName}"

}
```

}

but its giving all the build variant ie 2 debug and 2 release version name. I just want to have the currently selected build variant.

I would really appreciate any inputs in it. thanks in advance

Comment: There is no "currently selected build variant" at the time the Gradle script is run. The Gradle script builds a set of model objects that describe the build process, and at that point, all build variants are possible.

Comment: HI @CommonsWare , i got your point that model objects describe the build process. So is there any alternative that we can get the current build variant other than seeing from the studio itself. Thanks for replying the thread.

Comment: The typical approach, when using `applicationVariants.all`, is to define custom variant-specific tasks. Those tasks know the build variant that they are tied to. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity/blob/v0.0.1/netsecurity/build.gradle#L34-L47

Answer (score 2):

You can use in the variants loop: gradle.startParameter.taskNames[0]

Comment: that doesn't work if you are building all projects (`gradle assemble` command)

Answer (score 0):

in gradle:

```
ext.vMajor = 1
ext.vMinor = 9

def computeVersionName() {
    return String.format('%d.%d', vMajor, vMinor)
}
```

and in your code:

```
    PackageInfo pInfo = null;

    try {

        pInfo = YamsaferApplication.getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(YamsaferApplication.getContext().getPackageName(), 0);

        return pInfo.versionName;

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        Log.e("getAppVersion", "Error getting App version", e);

    }
```

Comment: here its taking the package info from the java files, but is there any way we can get the build variant from gradle itself